# How can I style a box with HTML and css like on

Tags: html, css

How can I make something like in wikihow, like a what's new page. Image, then text on top of it, like adding a caption to an image, with HTML and CSS? Is it even possible?

[image: wikihow example]

Comment: It is possible. You should show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 4):

Yes very possible.

```
<div class="container">
<img src="" class="photoSet">
<h2>Wonderful world</h2>
</div>


 .container h2 {
   position: absolute; 
   color: #fff;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   ......
   z-index: 2;
 }

.container{position: relative;}
```

another reference
http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/